# Drag the object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUbZz/

I need to move `lineH1` (it's `left` property) when I drag `cursorH1`. Right now, `lineH1` gets moved after next time I try to drag `cursorH1`. So I need it to happen when `cursoeH1` is moving. so that both `lineH1` & `cursorH1` will move simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the drag event in the draggable to move `lineH1`

```
$("#cursorH1").draggable({drag:function(e){MoveScale(this)}});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yUbZz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function () {
                    $("#cursorH1").draggable();
                    InitializeScale();
                });


function InitializeScale() {
    $('#cursorH1').on('mousemove', function () {
        $('#cursorH1').css({
            '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)',
            'filter': 'alpha(opacity=75)',
            '-moz-opacity': '0.75',
            '-khtml-opacity': '0.75',
            'opacity': '0.75'
        });
        $('#cursorH1').on('mousemove', MoveScale(this));
    });

    $('#cursorH1').on('mouseup', function () {
        $('#cursorH1').css({
            '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=35)',
            'filter': 'alpha(opacity=35)',
            '-moz-opacity': '0.35',
            '-khtml-opacity': '0.35',
            'opacity': '0.35'
        });
        //$('#cursorH1').off('mousemove');
    });
}

function MoveScale(e) {
    var offTop = e.offsetTop;
    var offLeft = e.offsetLeft;
    $('#lineH1').css('left', offLeft + 15);
}
```